# Different results produced by stack runghc vs stack ghci Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, megaparsec

I'm writing a parser using Megaparsec. Basically, the main file will open and read content of a file and then parsing that content.  When running the main file in ghci, everything was produced correctly
[img-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igqR3.png)

But when I tried running the Main file using stack runghc -- app/Main.hs, the weird parsing error happened:
[img-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4xpC.png)

Here is the project on GitHub: https://github.com/phuongduyphan/dbml-parser-haskell

Could sb have a look and tell me what am I doing wrong ? Why running the same main function results in different outputs from stack ghci and stack runghc ?

Answer (score 2):

I cloned your repository and tried:

```
stack runghc -- app/Main.hs holistics.dbml
```

And got:

```
Right 
( DBMLState 
    { tableS = fromList 
        [ 
            ( 0
            , NTable 
                { ntId = 0
                , ntGroupId = Nothing
                , ntName = "users" 
                , ntTableSettings = Nothing
                , ntFieldIds = [ 0 ]
                , ntIndexIds = []
                } 
            ) 
        ]
    , enumS = fromList []
    , refS = fromList []
    , tableGroupS = fromList []
    , fieldS = fromList 
        [ 
            ( 0
            , NField 
                { nfId = 0
                , nfTableId = 0
                , nfEnumId = Nothing
                , nfName = "id" 
                , nfType = "int" 
                , nfFieldSettings = Just [ FieldNote "abc" ]
                } 
            ) 
        ]
    , indexS = fromList []
    , endpointS = fromList []
    , tableIdCounter = 1
    , enumIdCounter = 0
    , refIdCounter = 0
    , tableGroupIdCounter = 0
    , fieldIdCounter = 1
    , indexIdCounter = 0
    , endpointIdCounter = 0
    } 
)
```

The problem is likely a problem with how stack or the local development environment is set up. For reference, running

```
stack --version
```

Gives me

```
Version 2.1.3, Git revision 636e3a759d51127df2b62f90772def126cdf6d1f (7735 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.31.2
```

Updating or re-installing stack could be a possible solution.